# Combobox Populando Cidades no Magento

Tags: php, magento

Tenho um combox que eu criei em PHP que popula cidades de um arquivo JSON e está funcionando 100%.
Eu precisava embutir esse combobox em uma pagina do Magento mas não estou conseguindo pois tenho varios arquivos JS,Jquery,JSON e includes de arquivos PHP dentro dele.
Tentei inserir via Bloco Statico

```
<? echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('nome_do_bloco')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Não sei a forma certa de efetuar as chamadas de js e includes .php no Magento

A pergunta é qual a melhor forma para chamar esse bloco dentro do Magento?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode colocar seu combobox em um arquivo e chamar onde quiser dessa maneira:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('page/html/pagina.phtml')->toHtml();?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('pagina'); ?>
```

Crie um arquivo onde desejar e chama, no exemplo acima foi criado uma pagina.phtml em `template/page/html`, o `getChildHtml('pagina')` é o nome da página sem extensão.

Agora se for querer salva a informação no banco, você precisa criar um atributo, e montar o combobox no formulário desejado.

Comment: Obrigado de certo!!

Comment: Aceita a resposta, assim sua pergunta não fica em aberto, abaixo da pontuação da minha pergunta tem um 'visto' clique nele. @BJJ